# SharpSvn GetLog ChangedPaths NodeKind is always Unknown

Tags: c#, .net, svn, sharpsvn

**Code**

```
using (var svnClient = new SvnClient())
{
    Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> svnLogEntries;
    svnClient.GetLog(new Uri("https://DbDiff.svn.codeplex.com/svn"), out svnLogEntries);
    foreach (var svnLogEntry in svnLogEntries)
    {
        foreach (var changedPath in svnLogEntry.ChangedPaths)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("NodeKind: " + changedPath.NodeKind + ", Path: " + changedPath.Path);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
NodeKind: Unknown, Path: /DbDiffCommon/DataAccess/SqlCommand11.xml
NodeKind: Unknown, Path: /DbDiffCommon/DataAccess/SqlCommand9.xml
NodeKind: Unknown, Path: /DbDiffCommon/DataAccess/SqlCommand11.xml
NodeKind: Unknown, Path: /DbDiffCommon/DataAccess/SqlCommand7.xml
NodeKind: Unknown, Path: /DbDiffCommon/DataAccess/SqlCommand8.xml
NodeKind: Unknown, Path: /DbDiffCommon/DataAccess/SqlCommand9.xml
NodeKind: Unknown, Path: /DbDiffCommon/Model/DatabaseConnectString.cs
NodeKind: Unknown, Path: /DbDiffCommon/Helper/Enums.cs
NodeKind: Unknown, Path: /DbDiffWinClient/Forms/frmRegisterServer.resx
NodeKind: Unknown, Path: /DbDiffWinClient/Forms/frmConnectDb.resx
NodeKind: Unknown, Path: /DbDiffWinClient/Forms/frmRegisterServer.cs
NodeKind: Unknown, Path: /DbDiffWinClient/Forms/frmConnectDb.cs
NodeKind: Unknown, Path: /DbDiffCommon/Model/RegisteredServer.cs
NodeKind: Unknown, Path: /DbDiffWinClient/ChangeLog.txt
NodeKind: Unknown, Path: /DbDiffWinClient/Forms/DbItems/ucTableDiffInfo.cs
NodeKind: Unknown, Path: /DbDiffCommon/DataAccess/DatabaseDataSets.cs
...
```

Why is `changedPath.NodeKind` always "Unknown"?  I would expect it to be "File" for the output above..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all servers send nodeKind for "log" request. See this discussion:
http://old.nabble.com/SVNNodeKind-%3D-UNKNOWN-td34018265.html#a34018265

Comment: NodeKind requires a Subversion 1.6+ repository format and repository. (And of course a new client, but you have that if you have the property in SharpSvn)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I can get the correct NodeKind using SvnClient.GetInfo but calling this for every changed path is very slow..

```
using (var svnClient = new SvnClient())
{
    Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> svnLogEntries;
    string repoUri = "https://DbDiff.svn.codeplex.com/svn";
    svnClient.GetLog(new Uri(repoUri), out svnLogEntries);
    foreach (var svnLogEntry in svnLogEntries)
    {
        foreach (var changedPath in svnLogEntry.ChangedPaths)
        {
            SvnInfoEventArgs svnInfo;
            svnClient.GetInfo(new SvnUriTarget(repoUri + changedPath.Path, svnLogEntry.Revision), out svnInfo);
            Debug.WriteLine("NodeKind: " + svnInfo.NodeKind + ", Path: " + changedPath.Path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You speedup it a bit using the following idea: if log contains "A com" and "A com/codeplex" entries, then "com" is a directory, no "info" request is required for it... For others --- yes --- you have to request nodeKind separately.

Comment: Codeplex is a proxy over TFS, implementing some of the Subversion apis at +- Subversion 1.6 level, but not all of the apis. E.g. blame support is broken.